# How can I generate title dynamically on ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use ionic pet template. 
I have a question about pet-detail page, if I would like to have a dynamic title on header, it will not show anything until I reload the page (using web browser), but I think it doesn't make sense since I would like to make an app. 
Does I miss anything? what can I do?

here is my code as below:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
<div class="buttons" ng-controller="BackCtrl">
    <a class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left" ng-click="$back()"></a>
</div>
<h1 class="title"> {{ current_pet.name }} </h1>
```

..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my app I've used this:

```
<ion-view title="{{Properties.Title}}">
```

Where Properties is a object on my scope(I have sort of a master controller) where I "override" on each "inner controller".

Comment: This does not work for me in Ionic 1.1.1 (neither new 1.2) - best voted answer from @dk123 did work for both 1.1.1/1.2

Comment: @AmirPopovich I did NOT downvote. I just commented. You don't have to predict future, just see the present...

Comment: If generating the title slightly after is doesn't seem to apply this to the view in time when it loads, and therefore shows up blank.  The <ion-nav-title> {{ PageTitle }} </ion-nav-title>  suggestion below works perfectly.  
Perhaps I'm missing something, what does "where I "override" on each "inner controller" mean?

Comment: @FrodmanG - This answer is over three years old. Ionic frameworks changed since then and I guess dk123's answer with 30 up votes became more relevant then this answer became. I still get up votes for this answer so I guess people are still using old versions of ionic and this does suit them.
Override on each inner controller means you have a master controller and nested pages (each page has a controller which is an inner controller). The inner controller overrides the property.

Answer (score 34):

If you happen to be using `ion-view`, use this:

```
<ion-nav-title>
    {{ PageTitle }}
</ion-nav-title>
```

And put it outside your `ion-content`.

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me as well on ionic 1.2

Comment: `'ion-nav-title' is not a known element`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  and you want to show a button in the header bar only when an input/textarea is filled (not empty), then you can do the following.

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-light">
  <h1 class="title">{{$root.Title}}</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button button-clear icon ion-checkmark-round" ng-click="" ng-if="$root.Title"></button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

and inside "ion-content" -

```
<div class="row>
  <textarea placeholder="" rows="3" maxlength="100" ng-model="$root.Title" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
</div>
```

Otherwise just using ng-if="Title" in the header bar will not work.